# Contact/Transactional e-mail does not work

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, email, contact-us

For Contact Us e-mails my yahoo e-mail address works  (xxxxx@yahoo.com) and receives the e-mails, but using my domain's e-mail (sales@mywebsite.com), they never arrive.  I've tested sales@mywebsite.com repeatedly and it works perfect.  My host, Nexcess, checked their e-mail log and said that Magento doesn't even attempt to send an e-mail when using sales@mywebsite.com.  My developer also used his e-mail address in Magento and it worked just like my Yahoo e-mail.

Any suggestions at all at what could be causing this?

Dave
CE 1.7.0.2

Answer (score 0):

If it is only not working for the domain that the website shares, then the server is probably routing the emails to itself.

Try disabling Nexcess email service.
http://docs.nexcess.net/article/how-to-disable-nexcess-email-for-remote-services.html